# How to create testrun attachment in azure devops using rest api via powershell

Tags: powershell, rest, azure-devops

I am trying to attach a html file to a test run via rest api using powershell task in my yaml. following is the task that I have used.

## - task: PowerShell@2

```
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              $username = "" 
              $token = "" 
              $instance = "" 
              $teamProjectName = ""

              #create auth header to use for REST calls 
              $accessToken = ("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$token) 
              $accessToken = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($accessToken) 
              $accessToken = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($accessToken) 
              $headers = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $accessToken)} 
              $runId = "12345"
              Write-Host $runId
              $filePath = "d:\a\1\UIAutomation\report123.html"
              $Stream = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAIAAABvFaqvAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAABlSURBVDhP7cxBCsAgDERR739pG/CnGJI0FopQ8O2cjNP6R85QbeNQU7wT1dkijaQ3vkZoWElaoTeJojW01cYh0jwfgiFBV/lEjOZtacijN/nLkOBHhIaVDgn+Wdycp6FXzlCl9wt0Y0cAzHo/zgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
              $uri = "https://$instance/$teamProjectName/_apis/test/Runs/$runId/attachments?api-version=5.1-preview.1"
              $body = @{
                        'stream' = $Stream
                        'fileName' = $filePath
                        'comment' = 'Test attachment upload'
                        'attachmentType' = 'GeneralAttachment'
                        }
              $testResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers $headers -Uri $uri -Body (ConvertTo-Json $body -Depth 10)
              Write-Host $testResult
```

I am getting an error in the console stating..

Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Invalid filename specified. Filename contains invalid

character ':'.\r\nParameter name: fileName","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssServiceException,

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common","typeKey":"VssServiceException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}

At D:\a_temp\077f26bc-c683-457d-be48-78fe5200d6a4.ps1:32 char:15

- ... estResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -ContentType 'application/ ...
- ```
  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc 

  eption

  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
  ```

### [error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.

Can someone help me with how to invoke the rest post method for attaching a file to a testrun?

Answer (score 1):

According to the error, it indicate Invalid filename specified.

From the official tutorial: [Attachments - Create Test Run Attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments/create%20test%20run%20attachment?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#testattachmentrequestmodel)

```
filename    string    Attachment filename
```

It's just the file name which should not include file path. Suggest you first run the Post API on same 3rd-party tool like postman, check if it works well with Azure DevOps and then move it to powershell script.

You could also take a look at this blog: [Azure DevOps Rest API. 17. Add Bugs and Attachments to Test Results](https://oshamrai.wordpress.com/2019/04/04/azure-devops-rest-api-17-add-bugs-and-attachments-to-test-results/) which use code to call same Rest API.